# Add Action e Controller no HTMLHelper do BeginForm com T4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, t4

Preciso adicionar no meu formulário de *template* no T4 o valor da *action* e do *controller*, mas não estou conseguindo entender como consigo passar os nomes deles.

Segue exemplo:

**CREATE.cs.t4**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RamoAtividades", FormMethod.post, new {@class = "form-horizontal"})) 
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="form-body">
```

Onde referencia *"Create"* e *"RamoAtividades*", precisaria que viesse de forma automática os valores.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você passa null para action e controller ele herdará os nomes de qual acontroller e action que o resultou

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.post, new {@class = "form-horizontal"})) 
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="form-body">
```

Comment: tentei colocar o `null` mas qndo gerei automaticamente o `controller` e as `views`, os valores continuaram como `null`em minhas `views.`

Comment: Quer dizer funcionou testei aqui e foi, só nao entendi como funciona a questão de estar nullo o algoritmo entender para qual controller ele tem que enviar os dados. Poderia me explicar? Obrigado

Comment: Toda requisição que você faz na aplicação é mapeado pelo httpContext,  logo você tem armazenado o nome da controller e a action chamada. No HtmlHelper ao chamar o BeginForm ele requer alguns como controller e action ao passar esses dois parametros nulos o HtmlHelper entende que o formulario a ser compilado não tem controller e action e automaticamente pega esses valores do request.

Comment: Show muito obrigado pela explicação. Valeu pela ajuda